# Why and how does node.js cast objects assigned to process.env to strings?

Tags: node.js

So, while working on my application, I tried assigned my config as an environment variables by creating a property `config` in the `process.env`.

However, while using it, I found out that `node.js` casts objects to string when assigned to `process.env`.

Here is a sample code to demonstrate this:

```
const config = {
    port: 3000,
    url: 'url'
}

process.env.config = config;

console.log(process.env.config) // prints '[object Object]'
console.log(typeof process.env.config) // prints 'string'
```

Is there any specific reason this happens?

Also, assuming `process.env` is an object passed to my application when it starts, HOW is this casting achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [8.9.4 API docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env)

> Assigning a property on process.env will implicitly convert the value to a string.

```
const config = { x : 1 };
const otherconfig = 1;

console.log(typeof config); // object
console.log(typeof otherconfig); // number

process.env.config = config;
console.log(process.env.config); // [object Object]
console.log(typeof process.env.config); // string

process.env.otherconfig = otherconfig; 
console.log(process.env.otherconfig); // 1
console.log(typeof process.env.otherconfig); // string
```

Why is casted as string ?

> The process.env property returns an object containing the user environment. See [environ](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)(7).

and looking at environ.

> The variable environ points to an array of pointers to **strings** called
>          the "environment".

So yeah its pretty low level its casted back and forth, because the `process` is an global variable and its always stored as string.

Just try to avoid defining environment variables this way its easier and less difficult to debug when the variables have been already defined or use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to make it a lot easier to define different configurations.

Answer (score -1):

The values in `process.env` typically come from the execution environment. So in a UNIX shell, you can issue a command like `MY_TEST_VALUE=abc123 node index.js` and in your `index.js` you will have access to a value `process.env.MY_TEST_VALUE`. Hence, everything in `process.env` is stored as strings.

That being said, you could always store a stringified JSON value in `process.env`:

```
process.env.CONFIG = JSON.stringify(config)
// and parse it when consuming 
parsedConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.CONFIG)
```

Comment: I get the initial startup storing, but once the process is initialized, how does the casting happen, and why is there a need to cast?